# I'm trying to print unicode characters from QPython

Tags: unicode, printing, qpython

Trying to print unicode characters like ┌┌┝├ from QPython 3.6 (under Android on a Chromebook with Chrome OS 100) but print(u"┌┌┝├") prints nothing, and using \u doesn't work since \ is the line continuation character in QPython. Perhaps the sandwiching of Android-over-Chrome OS-over-Linux makes this impossible - it's certainly beyond my diagnostic abilities - but I was hoping that a high-level language like Python might be able to bridge that gap...

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research it looks as though QPython 3.6's chr() function doesn't accept u"whatever" containing characters outside the ASCII set, ie. it isn't doing unicode at all

Answer (score 0):

OK, have answer, both simple and humiliatingly ridiculous. After wasting hours reading docs and forums, I was running my Unicode test program when I noticed the 'preferences' button, at top-right corner of QPython console screen (but not of editor screen) greyed-out so as to be almost illegible. Among those preferences is a tick box 'Default to UTF-8' and ticking it instantly cured my problems. I do love QPython very much, but its documentation, help and UI design are simply appalling - it's taken me two years to find this box, and no-one has ever mentioned it.